# My unity login with Firebase is not working

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

My register user is working perfectly, however when i try to log a user in i do not get any kind of message, successful login or failed login. I am trying to log my user in then move to my logged in screen. If anyone is able to see what it is i am doing wrong i would be very thankful!
I will provided my code below.
Thank you for your help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject email;
    public GameObject password;
    private string Email;
    private string Password;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        void Update () {
            if (email.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused){
                password.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (Password != ""&&Password != ""){
                LoginButton();
            }
        Email = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Password = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;    
    }

    public void LoginButton()
    {
                auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email, Password).ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
                }

                if (task.IsFaulted) {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }

                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScreen");

                    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread`, I think you should be good. If not, make sure you've enabled email sign in in the Firebase console.

I suspect that everything's working as expected, but because you're using `ContinueWith` your `SceneManager` logic is happening off of the main thread. In the best case scenario, this just won't work. In the worst case, you might see a crash.

See my [article on threading](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) in Unity and [my video on Authentication](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately it tells me that firebase doesn't accept that, the error i get is : " Assets\Scripts\Login.cs(29,71): error CS1061: 'Task<FirebaseUser>' does not contain a definition for 'ContinueWithOnMainThread' and no accessible extension method 'ContinueWithOnMainThread' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<FirebaseUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: You have to say `using Firebase.Extensions;`, see this documentation page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension . I'm so used to my specific IDE setup that I forget about using directives >.<